# how to implement deep reverse of different type sequence inscala

Tags: scala, vector, pattern-matching, scala-collections

If I have a Vector of different type number,say, `Vector("abcde",Vector(1,2,3),List(4,5,6),7)`, and I want to get a function:deep_reverse to reverse the vector deeply to `Vector(7,List(6,5,4),Vector(3,2,1),"edcba")`, I want something like:

```
def reverse2(xs:Seq[Any]):Seq[Any] = xs match{
case Seq() => Seq()
case a +: ys=> a match{
    case _:Seq[Any] =>reverse2(ys) ++: reverse2(a)
    case _:Int =>reverse2(ys) ++: Seq(a)
 }
```

but I can't pass the compiler, how to correct my code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

First off, this is really scary code because you should never use `Any`.  The whole point of type safety is to know the types of your data and allow the code to be guaranteed to work with them. This code throws away any of the benefits of using a typed language, and is really unsafe.  What happens if your Seq contains an Array?  Or a Double?  Or a user-defined class?  How should those be reversed?

That said, you're making things more complicated than they need to be.  Instead of doing your recursive approach through matching, just reverse the main list and then map over each element.

```
def reverse2(xs: Seq[Any]): Seq[Any] = {
  xs.reverse.map {
    case i: Int => i
    case s: String => s.reverse
    case s: Seq[Any] => reverse2(s)
  }
}
```

By the way: your compile error is due to the fact that `a` isn't known to be a `Seq[Any]` when you call `reverse2(a)`.  You need do something like `case b: Seq[Any] => ... reverse2(b)`.

Even if you fixed that you'd still get a *runtime* error since you're not handling `String`.

Comment: yeah! thanks ,your code works just as my expectation! but i change the first case statement in map : case i:Any => i ,for some extent type safe .for me, the point is just for any subclass of Seq[Any] and string, we need deep-reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close :)

```
    def reverse2(xs:Seq[Any]):Seq[Any] = xs match{
    case Seq() => Seq()
    case a +: ys=> a match{
        case x:Seq[Any] =>reverse2(ys) ++: reverse2(x)
        case y:Int =>reverse2(ys) ++: Seq(y)
     }
   }
```